# How to setup multiple Authorize.net payment gateways in Opencart?

Tags: opencart, payment, authorize.net, gateway

I currently use Authorize.net to handle my USD $ payments on my Opencart site. I'm trying to add the ability for customers to checkout with Euros and Pound Sterlings too. Thanks to the help of users here I was able to arrive at the conclusion that I need to setup additional Authorize.net payment gateways for each additional foreign currency I use on my site (in this case, for Euros and Pound Sterlings).

**My question is this; how do I setup multiple Authorize.net payment gateways in Opencart? I'm running v1.5.1 currently.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to copy all the `Authorize.NET` files into new payment modules (called e.g. *authorizenet_eur_aim* and *authorizenet_gbp_aim* with maybe renaming the default one into *authorizenet_usd_aim*) - both for admin and catalog sides.

For each of them you'll need to add a new setting in administration allowing you to set the currency code (e.g. `USD`) to be used for - this will be stored in the database.

Then in the model class of each *Authorize.NET* payment gateway when it is being decided whether this payment option is allowed to be used you would need to check the customer's currency set in the session

```
$this->currency->getCode() // should return value e.g. 'USD'
```

and the currency of each *Authorize.NET* payment gateway and display the matching one only.